# SBT binary incompatible issue scala-parser-combinators

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am new to the Scala env and trying to build a test project using play with 'scalikejdbc' for SQL integration. Here is my build.sbt following the documents at http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/playframework-support.html

```
name := """run"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    guice,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test,
  "com.h2database"  %  "h2"                           % "1.4.200", // your jdbc driver here
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"                  % "4.0.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-config"           % "4.0.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-play-initializer" % "2.8.0-scalikejdbc-3.5",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.3.1"

)
dependencyOverrides += "org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-core" % "0.10.3"

// Adds additional packages into Twirl
//TwirlKeys.templateImports += "com.example.controllers._"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
// play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport += "com.example.binders._"
```

I have also aded the below on plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("SBT Plugins", url("https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

However while trying to update the application before running i am getting the below issue

```
[error] (update) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error] 
[error]         * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.0 (early-semver) is selected over {1.1.2}
[error]             +- org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.13:4.0.0        (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]             +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.13:2.8.18                 (depends on 1.1.2)
[error]             +- com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.13:0.4.3            (depends on 1.1.2)
[error]
```

following are relevant versions :

```
sbt script version: 1.8.0
play version :2.8.18
Scala code runner version 3.2.1  but using as scalaVersion := "2.13.10" in sbt.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible

This means that you have at least two dependencies that are needing a 3rd one but they need 2 different versions which are *supposed* to be incompatible.

As only one can be included and used for your code, SBT is telling you: *"I am going to pick one version but there are risks that this version won't work as you might have code that rely on the other version and this might be incompatible"*.

You have 2 options:

- force a version (for `scala-parser-combinators`) with `dependencyOverrides` for instance if you know that actually there's no incompatibility, or at least on the way you use the libraries
- upgrade or downgrade the libraries (`scalikejdbc` or `play`) so that all libraries depend on the same version of the conflicting one (`scala-parser-combinators`).

  - In this case, I would downgrade `scalikejdbc` because there's no newer `play` version (as of today)

Comment: I guess `dependencyOverrides` should be instead of `overridesDependency`